# Flutter Provider is not Updating my Widget even though I tested the data is right?

Tags: flutter, dart

**problem:** I am trying to build a widget that gets data from a JSON file, but I am not sure why the provider is not updating the widget. *(no errors while debugging, simply no update on the widget happens.)*

This is the widget that is supposed to show the JSON data.

```
class CatalogPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CatalogPageState createState() => _CatalogPageState();
}

class _CatalogPageState extends State<CatalogPage>
    with AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin {
  @override
  bool get wantKeepAlive => true; // needed for keepAlive

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    super.build(context); // needed for keepAlive
    bool _loading = Provider.of<Screen1Provider>(context, listen: true).getLoading;
    List _catalogItems =
        Provider.of<Screen1Provider>(context, listen: false).getCatalogItems;
    return Scaffold(
        body: _loading == true
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            : ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _catalogItems.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(_catalogItems[index].code.toString()),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('hi from catalogPage!');
    Screen1Provider().updateJsonCatalog();
    super.initState();
  }
}
```

this is the provider data for the above widget

```
class Screen1Provider with ChangeNotifier {
  int _catalogPageIndex = 1;
  int _medidasPageIndex = 0;
  List _itemsCatalog = [];
  List _itemsMedidas = [];
  List _itemsExcluded = [];
  bool _loading = true;

  int get getCatalogPageIndex => _catalogPageIndex;

  bool get getLoading => _loading;

  void setLoading(bool boolean) {
    _loading = boolean;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setCatalogPageIndex(int index) {
    _catalogPageIndex = index;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setItemsCatalog(data) {
    _itemsCatalog = data;
    print('> setItemsCatalog');
    print(_itemsCatalog[0].code); //printing correctly here as well
    getItemsCatalog;
  }

  List get getItemsCatalog {
    print('> getItemsCatalog');
    if (_itemsCatalog.length > 0) {
      print(_itemsCatalog[0].desc); //printing correctly here as well
    }
    return _itemsCatalog;
  }

  void setItemsMedidasGroup(data) {
    // _itemsMedidas.addAll(data);
    // _itemsMedidas = data;
  }

  void setItemsExcluded(data) {
    // _itemsExcluded.addAll(data);
    // _itemsExcluded = data;
  }

  void updateJsonCatalog() {
    print('updating catalog');
    setLoading(true);
    _itemsCatalog.clear();
    _itemsMedidas.clear();
    _itemsExcluded.clear();

    getJsonCatalog().then((data) {
      setItemsCatalog(data[0]);
      // setItemsMedidasGroup(data[1]);
      // setItemsExcluded(data[2]);
      setLoading(false);
      print('> is loading?: $_loading');
    });
  }

  // Function to get catalog in json
  Future<List> getJsonCatalog() async {
    print('trying to download catalog...');
    List _returnList = [];
    String _url =
        'https://www.dropbox.com/s/qubo8rigrkkvnqm/DummyJsonTest.json?dl=1';
    try {
      var r = await http.get(_url);

      var jsonData = json.decode(r.body);

      // this is used to prevent Price error when it's empty
      // messes up with double.parse formulas
      String tempPrice;

      for (var header in jsonData) {
        if (header["CODIGO"] == '') {
          // skip if empty
          continue;
        }
        if (header["PRECIO"] == '') {
          tempPrice = '0.00';
        } else {
          tempPrice = header["PRECIO"];
        }
        CatalogItems item = CatalogItems(
          header["CODIGO"],
          header["DESCRIPCION"],
          header["INVENT"],
          double.parse(tempPrice).toStringAsFixed(2).toString(),
          header["COD.ALT."],
          header["DESC.ALT."],
          header["GRUPO"],
          (double.parse(tempPrice) * 0.8).toStringAsFixed(2).toString(),
        );
        // only add if item in CatalogItems.groups
        if (CatalogItems.groups.contains(header["GRUPO"])) {
          _itemsCatalog.add(item);
        } else if (CatalogItems.medidaGroups.contains(header["GRUPO"])) {
          _itemsMedidas.add(item);
        } else {
          _itemsExcluded.add(item);
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print('error');
      print(e);
    } finally {
      // this triggers even if catalog failed to download
    }
    // below will NOT trigger if an error was catched
    print('no errors while downloading JSON');
    print('${_itemsCatalog[0].code}|${_itemsCatalog[0].desc}|${_itemsCatalog[0].price}'); // prints correctly here
    _returnList = [_itemsCatalog, _itemsMedidas, _itemsExcluded];
    return _returnList;
  }
}
```

Please let me know if there could be a better way to do this as I am just learning about the provider.

**EDIT:** link of the project [https://www.dropbox.com/sh/k8v8d730p0qmbvl/AABG1jcPC_Zpu7O2yLk_idmxa?dl=0][1] please comment out the assets on pubspec.yaml file if there are errors.

**EDIT2:** added dummy json data link to the project so feel free to just run it. Otherwise this is the json data:

> [{"CODIGO": "13271190", "DESCRIPCION": "A/A CHE TRAX 13- GITY 2014-
>   SONI  13396514   95152912  52420930 CUK2", "INVENT": "890", "PRECIO":
>   "3.54", "COD.ALT.": "AC9205", "DESC.ALT.": "", "GRUPO": "10.FILTRO
>   A/A"}, {"CODIGO": "27274-7J125 SET", "DESCRIPCION": "A/A NIS
>   PATHFINDER NEW 2015 - 2PC   27275-1N605", "INVENT": "637", "PRECIO":
>   "4.42", "COD.ALT.": "AC2503 SET", "DESC.ALT.": "", "GRUPO": "10.FILTRO
>   A/A"}, {"CODIGO": "27274-EA000 SET", "DESCRIPCION": "A/A NIS FRONTIER
>   VQ40  YD25 PATHFIADER D40  VITARRA J20 27274-EL00A 27277-4JA0A",
>   "INVENT": "1072", "PRECIO": "4.25", "COD.ALT.": "AC2507SET",
>   "DESC.ALT.": "27277-4JA0A      GRAN VITARRA J20", "GRUPO": "10.FILTRO
>   A/A"}, {"CODIGO": "27274-EB700-F SET", "DESCRIPCION": "A/A NIS NAVARA
>   D40T  DELGADA 2 PCS  CA18320", "INVENT": "1117", "PRECIO": "4.22",
>   "COD.ALT.": "AC22005 SET", "DESC.ALT.": "", "GRUPO": "10.FILTRO A/A"},
>   {"CODIGO": "27275-1N601", "DESCRIPCION": "A/A NIS FRONTIER VQ25D -02
>   QG 16 ZD30 QD32", "INVENT": "314", "PRECIO": "4.95", "COD.ALT.":
>   "AC2502SET", "DESC.ALT.": "", "GRUPO": "10.FILTRO A/A"}, {"CODIGO":
>   "27277-00A26", "DESCRIPCION": "A/A NIS TIIDA C13 HR16 15- JUKE 2015-
>   HR16DE VERSA  27277-1KA0A", "INVENT": "2061", "PRECIO": "3.65",
>   "COD.ALT.": "AC0182", "DESC.ALT.": "", "GRUPO": "10.FILTRO A/A"},
>   {"CODIGO": "27277-1HA0A", "DESCRIPCION": "A/A NIS QASHQAI 13- VERSA
>   14- MARCH 13- ALMERA 11- K1267 27277-4BA0A", "INVENT": "1777",
>   "PRECIO": "3.82", "COD.ALT.": "AC2513", "DESC.ALT.": "", "GRUPO":
>   "10.FILTRO A/A"}, {"CODIGO": "27277-1KK0A", "DESCRIPCION": "A/A NIS
>   VERSA 2015- HOT", "INVENT": "2642", "PRECIO": "4.95", "COD.ALT.": "",
>   "DESC.ALT.": "", "GRUPO": "10.FILTRO A/A"}, {"CODIGO": "27277-3JC1B",
>   "DESCRIPCION": "A/A NI MURANO 14- PATHFINDER 2013- QR25D ALTIMA 12-",
>   "INVENT": "451", "PRECIO": "4.65", "COD.ALT.": "AC0208", "DESC.ALT.":
>   "", "GRUPO": "10.FILTRO A/A"}, {"CODIGO": "27277-4BA0A",
>   "DESCRIPCION": "A/A NIS XTRAIL 13- RENAULT CA18361   27277-1HA0A",
>   "INVENT": "426", "PRECIO": "3.71", "COD.ALT.": "A2514", "DESC.ALT.":
>   "", "GRUPO": "10.FILTRO A/A"}, {"CODIGO": "27277-4KH0A",
>   "DESCRIPCION": "A/A NI URBAN NV350 12- PASTROL 10-   PATHFHANER 16-
>   OF", "INVENT": "1420", "PRECIO": "3.89", "COD.ALT.": "27277-5JJ0A",
>   "DESC.ALT.": "", "GRUPO": "10.FILTRO A/A"}]

**Edit3:** Improved debugging prints, verified boolean trigger is correct. But widget is still not updating (CircularProgressIndicator() should only show if boolean is false, but it keeps spinning forever)

```
I/flutter ( 5948): hi from catalogPage!
I/flutter ( 5948): updating catalog
I/flutter ( 5948): trying to download catalog...
I/flutter ( 5948): > getItemsCatalog
I/flutter ( 5948): no errors, done
I/flutter ( 5948): 13271190|A/A CHE TRAX 13- GITY 2014-   SONI  13396514   95152912  52420930 CUK2|3.54
I/flutter ( 5948): > setItemsCatalog
I/flutter ( 5948): 13271190
I/flutter ( 5948): > getItemsCatalog
I/flutter ( 5948): A/A CHE TRAX 13- GITY 2014-   SONI  13396514   95152912  52420930 CUK2
I/flutter ( 5948): > is loading?: false
```

Comment: Why did you pass `listen: false` to `Provider.of`?

Comment: i thought because the trigger of change was from the boolean and not from the array. I'll test if it makes any difference if i put true on both.
edit: yeah no difference on true or false.

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot without the full code.  Could you use breakpoints to verify that the List variables are actually getting data? (_itemsCatalog, _itemsMedida, etc)

Comment: You also might put more print() statements in your code in order to verify that all the pieces are being run and in what order.  I suspect that there is a problem of timing with async values. (but, again, it's hard to test without the code)

Comment: updated post to include the prints where the data was successfully parsed correctly and also added link for the full project. Let me know if it helps. thanks

Comment: @WilliamTerrill hi can you please check? you are my last hope for this >.<

Comment: thank god. I can't progress anymore because of this. thanks :D

Comment: I took a look at the code, and something that I'm currently investigating is that the code instantiates the Screen1Provider twice.  I added a constructor to the Screen1Provider in order to catch it, but, I'm still trying to figure out where it's being instantiated the second time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is in this piece of code in your CatalogPage() class:

```
  void initState() {
    print('hi from catalogPage!');
    Screen1Provider().updateJsonCatalog();  // <----- The culprit
    super.initState();
  }
```

The way that I found it was to add a constructor to the Screen1Provider that looks like this:

```
Screen1Provider(){
   print("***started provider***");
}
```

and I noticed that line was printed twice...and a provider is only instantiated once after the first use.

When you called Screen1Provider().updateJsonCatalog(), it made a new instance of ScreenProvider outside of the ChangeNotifierProvider() in your main.dart file.  This is what was breaking the notifyListeners call.  In order to call the code, you need to run:

```
Provider.of<Screen1Provider>(context, listen: false).updateJsonCatalog();
```

After that, the code works just fine... well... there are still some opportunities, but I was able to see this:
[image]

Wow.  That was a really subtle error! (I also learned a couple of things looking at your code... so it was win/win all the way around!

Comment: I never thought calling the method directly would cause this problem lol. Thank you very much for solving this.

Comment: jesus I got stuck for so long I was going crazy, thanks again for figuring it out. How long did it take you?

Comment: probably about two hours. I had never seen that particular problem before. It was definitely subtle!

Comment: yup, I am. How did you figure it out? 

Comment: muy clever William hahaha